# Rails - Customize RABL JSON Output for JS Flot Graphs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, flot, rabl

I'm creating an API for my application. To create my API, I use RABL, and I'm planning to use my API data for [JS Flot Charts](http://www.flotcharts.orgs). The input structure of flot is the following:

```
{
        "label":"Total Orders",
        "dataBar":[
            [
                1325376000000,
                45023
            ],
            [
               1325462400000,
                23090
            ],
            [
                1325548800000,
                49002
            ],
            [
                1325635200000 ,
                32909
            ],
            [
                1325721600000,
                80211
            ]
        ]
    }
```

However RABL outputs the following JSON:

```
[{"order":{"total":"120.0","store_id":244234563,"completed_at":1358432510000}},{"order":{"total":"120.0","store_id":244234563,"completed_at":1358432513000}},{"order":{"total":"120.0","store_id":244234563,"completed_at":1358432515000}}]
```

How should I modify the RABL's structure in order to use it in Flot ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about RABL, but it's a jquery one-liner on the javascript side:

```
var data = [{"order":{"total":"120.0","store_id":244234563,"completed_at":1358432510000}},{"order":{"total":"120.0","store_id":244234563,"completed_at":1358432513000}},{"order":{"total":"120.0","store_id":244234563,"completed_at":1358432515000}}]
var flotData = $.map(data, function(i){ return [[i.order.completed_at, parseInt(i.order.total)]] });
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Sorry about that, I loaded and it's working now. However it's returning '1358432545000,240,1359474090000,720' Whereas I want it to be => [1358432545000,240],[1359474090000,720] and so on.. How should I modify that ?

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it again (jquery 1.7.1 and Chrome 24) and it works as expected.  Are you usre you have double `[[` after the return?